# cakephp limit results find('all')

Tags: cakephp, controller, find

I just want to show on index.ctp all results from a model wich are true as conditions. Like this select:

select * from revistas where isonline = 'true';

Ive tried this code below on controller:

```
public function index() {
        //$iscond = $this->Revista->findAllByNome('testa');
        //$this->Revista->query("SELECT id, nome, acronimo, modified, user_id from xconv.revistas where isonline = 't'");
        $this->Revista->find('all', array(
            'contain' => array( 
                'conditions' => array('Revista.isonline' => 't'))));
        $this->Revista->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('revistas', $this->paginate());
    }
```

Those 2 comments above tried b4. It doesn return any errors, but dont do the condition.

Is there any other file of the MVC to write more code ? What went wrong ??

Ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR:**

You need to supply your conditions to the actual pagination as opposed to doing a `find()` query, then doing a completely separate `$this->paginate()`.

**Explanation:**

`$this->paginate();` will actually run a query for you.  So - basically, in your question, you're running a query for no reason, then doing `paginate()` which runs another query that has no conditions.

Instead, apply the condition like this:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array('conditions'=>array('Revista.isonline' => 't'));
$this->paginate();
```

**Note:** As noted by your comment and another answer, there are multiple ways to apply conditions to paginate - the main point to this answer is pointing out that you need to apply the conditions to the paginate, not a previous query.

Comment: Dave, ty for the help... it put me on the right direction to solve this particular problem, but the solution occured when i wrote on the controller this:
 public $paginate = array(
  'limit' => 30,
  'conditions'=>array('Revista.isonline' => 't')
  );

Comment: @josemey - yep, that's another way to apply conditions to paginate.  The only downside, is, that applies it to all paginates within that controller instead of just the specific action.

Comment: Just to let u know yr code did not word properly. Matter of fact it returned an error as shown below:Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property RevistasController::$Paginator has no effect [APP/Controller/RevistasController.php, line 13] and in the records :Notice (8): Undefined variable: revistas [APP/View/Revistas/index.ctp, line 14]

Comment: @josemey please debug a LITTLE on your own.  1) One of the errors you're showing regarding `revistas` variable is not even in my code.  2) are you including the Paginator component?  3) the main answer is the same... I've informed you that you should add the options to paginate, not a previous/unrelated query - how you go about adding the options is up to you and is written in roughly 10,463 online tutorials on how to use CakePHP pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Using your clues at @Dave's answer comments, I think this is a solution with the "paginator filter",

```
public function index() {
    $this->Revista->recursive = 0;  //your old code
    $this->paginate['conditions']=array('Revista.isonline' => 't'); //new code
    $this->set('revistas', $this->paginate());  //your old code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
public function index() {

        $this->Revista->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array('Revista.isonline' => 't')));
        $this->Revista->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('revistas', $this->paginate());
    }
```

Comment: hi, ty for the help, but i tried this b4 use the type 'contain'. Same results.